# header re loading when loading a new page on wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, plugins, header, loading

I'm developing a website on wordpress.
I've finished building my website but I have a problem.
I have a #header section with my menu, and an .entry section with my pages.
I wanted to know if there's a way of stopping my header from reloading every time I have a new page.
is there a wordpress plugin ? a javascript code ? or anything else... 
the problem is that my header displays new informations depending on wich page is displayed.. for example I have a gallery and my header displays a counter...
well I hope you understand what I'm asking and hope you can help me !
thanks

Answer (score 1):

there is 2 ways to do this i think

- ajax load your section of page
- use iframes to load body